# STSDEV and SharePoint 2010 - The command exited with code 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, moss

I'm fairly new to programming but experienced with SharePoint.  I have been given a solution to work on and have been having trouble getting it to actually build. The error I get is:

Error  3   The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\bin\stsadm.exe" -o execadmsvcjobs" exited with code 3.  Solution.Name

What I've deduced is that this is a SharePoint 2010 solution.  I can tell this because the feature ID is the same in the solutionconfig.xml file as it is in my 2010 farm.  There is no manifest.xml in my file structure, which i find odd.  Maybe it was renamed?

I figured out this solution was built using STSDev.  I found info about that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337895.aspx)

I'm not sure if this ever worked for SharePoint 2010 or how as it clearly seems to be targeted to 2007 deployments (thus the reference to the 12 hive).  I actually get the same error if I try to build this in my 2007 environment.

Do solutions built with STSDev even work for SP 2010?

Could someone please explain to me why I can't get this to build or what I need to do to get this to build in 2010?  If you need more info, I'd be happy to provide it.  Due to my greeness, I'm not sure what more info you would need.

Below is the link to the MS Forum where I originally posted this question.  I have not received any answers.

[MS Forum Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6232a4f6-3b6f-4885-bd9b-8d138abfdfd5/vs2010-command-exited-with-code-3-postbuild-events?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, by removing all the Post Build events, going into Configuration Manager and changing Active Solution Configuration to ReleaseBuild, I was able to get it to build successfully.  I was then able to deploy the wsp.  I don't know why all the SP 2007 stuff was in DebugBuild or why that was the default.  Perhaps I'll figure it all out as I continue on.  Figured it was something I was missing.  Hopefully others new to programming and VS can benefit from this.